# Tensorflow / Keras Python CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm doing a project where a python script used a convolutional neural network to determine if a plant is healthy, and then water it based on that. While training the CNN, it seems to get up to 100% accuracy quite early, although it isn't accurate. I only have a little less than 2000 images, and was wondering if I didn't have enough, or it was my model, which is here

```
        self.model = Sequential()
        self.model.add(Conv2D(numFilters, filterSize, activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(numFilters * 2, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=poolSize))
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.25))
        self.model.add(Flatten())
        self.model.add(Dense(numFilters * 4, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))
        self.model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
        self.model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      optimizer = 'adam',
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I would just like to know the reason why it doesn't train well.
Thanks.

Comment: add regularization layer, augmentation. Your model is overfitting I guess. Check if there is class imbalance

Comment: Try calculating ROC-AUC score if dataset is balanced or PRC score. If the score is around 50 % then your model is just random guessing. 
If you have 2k images go for transfer learning with data Aug & label smoothing. Overfit the model and then apply regularization one by one.